# How to transform this foreach to Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
int j = 0;  
foreach (var e in XmlData.Elements())  
{  
   xDictionary.Add(j++, e.Value);  
}
```

Comment: Is `xDictionary` an existing dictionary that contains some items or will it always be empty (i.e., you're building it from scratch)?  If it exists, then LINQ really isn't what you should be using here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using a dictionary if the key is simply the positional index. I'd suggest using a list instead:

```
var xList = XmlData.Elements().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this would do it, using [the overload of `Select` which provides the index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx), and [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx):

```
var dictionary = XmlData.Elements()
                        .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.index, x => x.value);
```

That's assuming `xDictionary` was empty before you started.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: To create a new dictionary:

```
var dict = XmlData.Elements()
        .Select((e, i) => new {Element = e, Index = i})
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Index, p => p.Element.Value);
```

Also if you want to add to an **existing** dictionary you can use an `AddRange` convenience extension method:

```
xDictionary.AddRange(XmlData.Elements()
                    .Select((e, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, e.Value)));
```

And the extension method implementation:

```
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> source, IEnumerable<T> elements)
    {
        foreach (T element in elements)
        {
            source.Add(element);
        }
    }
```